# Java applet on GlassFish 3.0.1 server

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, applet, awt

I have developed an applet and I am using a JSP to upload it.  I have worked it using Netbeans 6.9.  The applet works fine without JSP.  When I run JSP on Glassfish server, applet does not run.

My applet takes 43 seconds to do processing and get displayed, I think this may be the problem.

---

When I run the same JSP with the same applet but with slight modification, applet runs correctly with JSP. Modification is that I comment out a function call (called from `init()` method) which is responsible for large execution time.  The long running method reads three files and generates the output in the choice buttons, i.e. generates the choices.

But I need that function in my applet, that is very important function.

Every catch statement has a `printstacktrace()` method call in it.

```
public void start(){
   initialise_maps();
}


public void init() {
    try {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run() {
                initComponents();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
 //   initialise_maps();
}
```

Comment: 1) Did you have a question?  2) Do you have an URL where we can visit the applet? 3) Does the Java Console report any errors?  (If so, what are they? 4) Does the code ignore exceptions?  5) *"The applet works fine without JSP."*  How do you run it then?  Is it the IDE that launches it?  6) What is the output of the JSP?  7) What is the code used?  **Note** So as not to waste your time (or more importantly, mine), please ensure each question is answered.

Comment: 1)Yes, the problem is that the applet is not working in JSP(may be due to large execution time).2)Sorry, I dont have any url to applet.Infact I am working to put it on web. 3)No errors are repoted. 4)It does not ignore any exceptions. 5)I run it using IDE.

Comment: <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Winter School Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>WELCOME:</h1>
        <applet code="org.manish.ws.WSApplet" archive="WSApplet.jar" width="600" height="420"/>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: above comment is the content of JSP file

Comment: *"3)No errors are repoted."*  If the download timed out, I expect there would be errors.  Are you ***certain*** that every `catch` in the code calls `printStackTrace()` (or logs, etc.) the `Throwable`?

Comment: yes, I am sure. When I run the same JSP with the same applet but with slight modification,applet runs correctly with JSP. Modification is that I comment out a function call which is responsible for large execution time.But i need that function in my applet,that is very important function.And yes, every catch statement has a printstacktrace() method call in it.

Comment: Which method (e.g. `init()`/`start()` etc.) is that method called from?

Comment: that function is called from init() method

Comment: BTW - what exactly does 'that function' do?  Get results from a DB, create a very complex image, put the cat out, ..what?

Comment: It does data processing.It reads three files and generates the output in the choice buttons,i.e,generates the choices.

Comment: And the applet is designed using AWT

Comment: *"..the applet is designed using AWT"*  Why use AWT components rather than Swing, in this millennium?  There is no need for it, and you can get better answers for Swing, which people have *not* forgotten!

Answer (score 0):

> Modification is that I comment out a function call (called from `init()` method) which is responsible for large execution time.

It seems it will be necessary to refactor that method call to the `start()` method, or do it in a separate `Thread` (e.g. using a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)).

---

> The long running method reads three files and generates the output in the choice buttons, i.e. generates the choices.

*Add* the choice boxes in the `init()` method, but *populate* them in the `start()` method (if not already done - the start method is called every time the browser is restored from minimized, as well as directly after `init()`).

Comment: public void start(){
       initialise_maps();
    }


    public void init() {
        try {
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run() {
                    initComponents();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
     //   initialise_maps();
    }

Comment: Please edit that code into your question and use the code formatting button (it has text '{}') after selecting it.

Comment: It is one of the 12 icons that appear above the text area of the message posting/editing form.

Comment: Yes, basically.  Did it work for your applet?  And if the answer is 'no', make sure you clear the class cache(1) and try it again.  1) That can be achieved by opening the Java console, and typing 'x' (from memory - check the options listed).